# Best way to store common system preferences in a microservices architecture (serverless application)

Tags: amazon-web-services, microservices, serverless

We have a multi-tenant app with a serverless backend that is all microservices using API gateway, lambda, DDB, SQS, SNS,Cognito etc.

Microservices are all about decomposing systems into separate components. However, some things in a system seem centralized in nature. My concern is about the settings/preferences for each tenant which will have settings (like units, decimal places e.t.c) set through a preferences page on app UI for each tenant and be applied to all users of that tenant and are pertaining to different parts of the system with each having its own microservice. What's the best way to approach system settings for each tenant in microservices with each having its own database.

1. If it was user preference, I'd have stored it in Cognito but it's tenant wide preference (and not user preference).
2. I don't think a new microservice for system preferences would be a good way because then it will lead to a lot of cross-service communication.

What's the best way to address it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to store system settings, I suggest storing them in [SSM Parameter Store](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/systems-manager-parameter-store.html).

You can store values as plain text or encrypted, you can control the access to parameters with IAM roles and permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your response. These are tenant preferences we are talking about like how many decimal points do they want to have in the numbers they are looking at and what units they want to see measurements in.  It actually makes sense. Now that you say that, we could make a request to SSM through middy middleware and just forward it to our microservices, Am I understanding you right?

Comment: Also, these settings are actually selected by the tenant Admin from application UI, This is not system config.

Comment: These are preferences set by tenant admins through system preferences screens so they can change YES. Not often though. But since they change at runtime, I am guessing loading through middy middleware would be ideal.

What I am not sure about it is - why store them in SSM when DDB reads are much faster?

Why not have a common table that is accessed by the middleware and loads the preferences for the user based on the tenant they belong to, instead of loading them through SSM which will add more latency compared to Dynamo. What's the advantage?

Comment: There is no advantage if they can change. DynamoDB can be a better solution. The advantage of SSM is that you store parameters without having to deal with all the overhead of a DynamoDB table. SSM is not a database after all, it does not have all the properties of a fully fledged DB. Now, that you explained your situation in depth, DynamoDB would be a better fir for you.